# RPi Quadcopter under RISC OS

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, riscos

it is well known that the pi is in recommended for the quadcopter as raspbian is not a real time operating system

the question is, will using RISC OS offer any advantage over raspbian, and make the Pi DIY Quadcopter friendly

### thanks in advance

why there os no quadcopter tag?